# Storing Pandas dataframe in working memory

Tags: python, pandas, binaryfiles

Is there some way to take a dataframe, say,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
```

and store it in temp memory as a binary object that can then be opened with

```
open(df, 'rb')
```

So then, rather than do something like

```
open('/home/user/data.csv', 'rb')
```

the code would be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

df_rb = *command to store in temp working memory as binary readable*

open(df_rb, 'rb')
```

Comment: Look into Python's `pickle` module: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html

Comment: ive tried with that, but then i cant extract the filepath with it. so i would need to pickle it, get a filepath (without specifying a filepath), and then use with open. is there some way to do that?

Comment: Simply dump the DataFrame to a in-memory byte stream (using e.g. `BytesIO` https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead of to a file.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to build a work around to a Django REST API issue; i posted an in depth question around that, but i think it was too in depth. This will give a simple work around without having to change up my django api source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has **[`df.to_pickle()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)** method:

From the docs:

> Pickle (serialize) object to file.

```
df.to_pickle("./dummy.pkl")
```

Then read this pickled df using **[`read_pickle()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html#pandas.read_pickle)**

From the docs:

> Load pickled pandas object (or any object) from file.

```
unpickled_df = pd.read_pickle("./dummy.pkl")
```

Comment: will the "./dummy.filetype" work on any computer? what i mean is, is there any risk to someone downloading a function i write, running the function (writing a file to './file'), and getting some "directory does not exist" error? it seems like that couldnt be the case

Comment: I think it will run on any machine. You can always handle the case where pickle writes in a dir that always exists.

Comment: This does not work if there is no filesystem, e.g. aws lambda

Answer (score 5):

You could pickle it to an io.BytesIO object which is *in memory*

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle, io
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
f = io.BytesIO()
pickle.dump(df,f)
f.seek(0)    # necessary to start reading at the beginning of the "file"
dg = pickle.load(f)

In [48]: dg==df
Out[48]: 
      a     b
0  True  True
1  True  True
2  True  True
```

Comment: this was helpful.. the df.to_pickle will close the io object though, so I preferred to use `pickle.dump` so I could control when I closed it personally.

Comment: @NickBrady - thanx.